# AndroidManifest Merging Errors: Error: uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 11 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services, android-manifest

This is the merging error.

- AndroidManifest Merging Errors: Error: uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 11 cannot be smaller than version 14 declared in library ..android\build-cache\570d870ca8b91d8f399eeac1eabcca1d94c4782f\output\AndroidManifest.xml Suggestion: use tools:overrideLibrary="com.google.android.gms.iid

How to solve it?

Comment: set `minSdkVersion` to 14

Comment: please describe how?, as i'm new to android studio.

Comment: Check my answer below please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume you are using the latest version of play services. *Google play services have stopped supporting sdk versions lower than 14*. So, you have to set your `minSdkVersion` to 14. To change that, you have to go to app gradle file, there inside `defaultConfig` brace, set `minSdkVersion` to 14. After that, sync gradle then build and run the project.

```
defaultConfig {
       .....
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
```

If you really need to set `minSdkVersion` to 11 (or lower than 14), **use previous versions** of play services.